# Can't send data to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to send some data to firebase but showing nothing

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private TextView txtDetails;
    private EditText name,age,gender,mobile,address,blood,bp,date;
    private Button submit;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseInstance;
    private DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase;
    private String patientId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtDetails = findViewById(R.id.txtheading);
        name = findViewById(R.id.edname);
        age = findViewById(R.id.edage);
        gender = findViewById(R.id.edgender);
        mobile = findViewById(R.id.edmobile);
        blood = findViewById(R.id.edblood);
        bp = findViewById(R.id.edbp);
        date = findViewById(R.id.eddate);
        submit = findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);

        firebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase = firebaseInstance.getReference("Doctor");

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String Name = name.getText().toString();
                String Age = age.getText().toString();
                String Gender = gender.getText().toString();
                String Mobile = mobile.getText().toString();
                String Blood = blood.getText().toString();
                String BP = bp.getText().toString();
                String Date = date.getText().toString();

             if(TextUtils.isEmpty(patientId)) {
                 createPatient(Name,Age,Gender,Mobile,Blood,BP,Date);
             }
             else {

                 updatePatient(Name,Age,Gender,Mobile,Blood,BP,Date);
             }
            }
        });

    }

    private void updatePatient(String name, String age, String gender,
                               String mobile, String blood,
                               String bp, String date) {



    }
    private void createPatient(String name, String age, String gender,
                               String mobile, String blood, String bp, String date) {

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(patientId)) {

            patientId = firebaseDatabase.push().getKey();
        }

        Patient patient = new Patient(name,age,gender,mobile,blood,bp,date);
        firebaseDatabase.child(patientId).setValue(patient);
        addUserChangeListener();

    }

    private void addUserChangeListener() {

           firebaseDatabase.child(patientId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                   Patient patient = dataSnapshot.getValue(Patient.class);
                   if(patient==null) {


                       Log.e(TAG, "User data is changed !" );
                       return;
                   }

                   Log.e(TAG, "User data is changed!" + patient.Names + ", " + patient.Address +", "+patient.Age +
                   "," +patient.Blood +"," +patient.BP+ "," +patient.Gender +
                   "," +patient.Mobile + "," +patient.Date);



               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                   Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read user", databaseError.toException());
               }
           });

    }


   }
```

Here is my `Patient` Class :

```
    public class Patient {

    public String Names;
    public String Age;
    public String Gender;
    public String Mobile;
    public String Address;
    public String Blood;
    public String BP;
    public String Date;


   public Patient(String name, String age, String gender, String mobile, String blood, String bp, String date) {
   }

    public Patient(String names, String age, String gender,
                   String mobile, String address, String blood,
                   String BP, String date) {
        Names = names;
        Age = age;
        Gender = gender;
        Mobile = mobile;
        Address = address;
        Blood = blood;
        this.BP = BP;
        Date = date;
    }

    public Patient(String name, String age, String gender, String mobile, String blood, String bp, String date) {
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the Patient class

Comment: @svi.data I edited , please check

Answer (score 0):

First remove this:

```
       if(TextUtils.isEmpty(patientId)) {

         }
```

from this:

```
        createPatient(Name,Age,Gender,Mobile,Blood,BP,Date);
```

and this:

```
        patientId = firebaseDatabase.push().getKey();
```

then use a map instead of class to store the info.

So delete this

```
  Patient patient = new Patient(name,age,gender,mobile,blood,bp,date);
```

and createPatient method will look like this

```
    private void createPatient(String name, String age, String gender,
                           String mobile, String blood, String bp, String date) {



     //create a push id like that
     patientId = firebaseDatabase.push().getKey();

     //make a map called patientmap

     Map patientmap=new HashMap();

     //add your values like this to the map

      patientmap.put("Name",name);
      patientmap.put("Age",age);
      patientmap.put("Gender",gender);
      patientmap.put("Mobile",mobile);
      patientmap.put("Blood",blood);
      patientmap.put("BP",bp);
      patientmap.put("Date",date);

    firebaseDatabase.child(patientId).setValue(patientmap);
    addUserChangeListener();

}
```

Comment: please check the new answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks , I'll try urs and let u know